# Equivalent of partials in Razor Pages

Tags: ajax, razor-pages

I've recently started using Razor Pages, coming from using MVC for years.  In MVC, I think a common pattern is to have a view which is loaded via AJAX with by returning it as a partial view from the controller (and sometimes directly embedding the same partial in a Razor view).

In Razor Pages, I can't work out what the equivalent approach of this should be.  I know that I can add a controller method to a page to a separate Razor view and I'm not sure if that can be returned as as partial, but this feels very messy, especially if the Partial View is used by other Pages as well.

Should I be using MVC for partials?  Or Razor Components?  Or View Components? (I'm not very familiar with the last 2 of these).  Am I missing something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use partials in Razor Pages for this requirement all the time. But I return them from *named handler methods* in a `PageModel` class:  https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/handler-methods#named-handler-methods.

Here's some code based on a fuller explanation on my site (https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/ajax/partial-update)

A `PageModel` class that includes a named handler (`OnGetCarPartial`). It returns a `PartialViewResult`:

```cs
public class AjaxPartialModel : PageModel
{
    private ICarService _carService;
    public AjaxPartialModel(ICarService carService)
    {
        _carService = carService;
    }
    public List<Car> Cars { get; set; }
    public void OnGet()
    {
    }
    public PartialViewResult OnGetCarPartial()
    {
        Cars = _carService.GetAll();
        return Partial("_CarPartial", Cars);
    }
}
```

And the code in the calling page that uses Fetch to call the named handler (passing its name without the `On[HTTP method]` prefix to a query string key named "handler") and then plug the HTML that is returned in the response into the page:

```html
@page
@model RazorPagesTests.Pages.AjaxPartialModel
<h2>Ajax</h2>
<p><button class="btn btn-primary" id="load">Load</button></p>
<div id="grid"></div>
@section scripts{
    <script>
        document.querySelector('#load').addEventListener('click', () => {
            fetch('/ajaxpartial?handler=CarPartial')
                .then(response => response.text())
                .then(html => document.querySelector('#grid').innerHTML = html);
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: what happens if you want to use it from multiple Pages though?  It seems messy to have it tied into that specific Page in that case?

Comment: @wizzardmr42 Technically, there is no reason why you can't call the same URL from any page. But if that idea bugs you, you can fall back on to a standard MVC controller that isn't tied to a specific page.

Comment: I know that you can, but it feels like poor code organisation. Is there no concept of partial pages or anything?

Comment: Yes, partial pages exist. I've explained how they work. There's going to have to be a trade-off f you want to call the same partial from multiple places, just like in MVC.

Comment: Can you return Partial from OnGet and if so, is that not recommended for some reason? Just that would probably be more like I was expecting

Comment: Yes, absolutely. That works. Although if I was adding Razor Pages to act purely as partials, I would design the page to return just the HTML I needed and not bother about `PartialResult`s. Set the layout to null in the page so that it doesn't pick up the default layout. I might even include "Partial" as part of the page name to distinguish it from actual pages.

Comment: @wizzardmr42 Prompted by your question, I've started to take up the approach of using  full Razor Pages for partials as described above. I have to say, so far, I really like it. It provides a really clean way to do progressive enhancement in Razor Pages.

Comment: Brilliant!  I'm busy on an API project at the moment, but I look forward to trying it!